# How do i add extra functionality to an existing tinyMCE button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to add some extra functionality to the standard buttons in tinyMCE and I was wondering how this can be done.

For example,

If i want this paste button to not only paste the content,
But do some custom things as well. (like add a class, or change the size etc).

[image: TinyMCE Buttons]

How do i extend the functionality of such a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was easier with Tinymce3 where it was very easy to get the button and change the executed command.

Now with Tinymce4 you can solve this as follows:

- unbind any events of the paste-Span in the dom and bind your own click-handler executing your custom code and then the regular tinymce paste command